# Javascript change source image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to change the src= image of a parent in a nested ul li when I click on a link. Below is my code. I know how to change the src= with javascript, but I don't know how many tiers I need to navigate up to change the src= image. Example: I want to change src="test.png" when I click on Question1.Answer1.

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>    
    <style>
        ul {
            list-style: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        li {
            /*background-image: url(/images/page.png);*/
            background-position: 0 1px;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            padding-left: 20px;
        }

        a {
            color: #000000;
            cursor: pointer;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        a:hover {
            text-decoration: underline;
        }

        .hidden {
        display:none;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="/js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function addLine(what) {
                $("#" + what).append('<li>URL to uploaded document</li>');
            };

            function myToggle(what){
                $("#" + what).toggleClass('hidden');
            };
    function deleteLine(what) {
        $(what).parent().children().remove();
    }
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <ul>
            <li class="folder">
                <a href="#" onClick="myToggle('Test1');">Test</a>
                <ul class="hidden" id="Test1">
                    <li class="folder"><img src="test.png">
                        <a href="#" onClick="myToggle('Test1-2');">Test1-2</a>
                        <ul class="hidden" id="Test1-2">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" onClick="addLine('Question1');">This is Question 1</a>
                                <ul id="Question1"><li onClick="deleteLine(this)"> Questoin1.Answer1</li></ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" onClick="addLine('Question2');">This is Question 2</a>
                                <ul id="Question2"></ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" onClick="addLine('Question3');">This is Question 1</a>
                                <ul id="Question3"></ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: *Why* are you using jQuery *and* inline event-handlers (`onClick`)?

Comment: Nothing wrong with using inline event handlers with jQuery. The real question is why aren't you scouring the jQuery documentation to find out what its API offers. If you only stydy at the section on [DOM traversal](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) you'll find your solution.

Comment: @cookie: my point wasn't that it's any more wrong with jQuery, my point is simply that jQuery makes it so easy to avoid inline-event-handling it seems more deliberately, and purposefully, masochistic.

Comment: I am using both, because its the only way I know how to pass specific values to the jquery code. I am pretty new to jquery, so any specific help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Will the image that you want to change the src attribute for always be an image within an <li> with a class of folder? If so, you can traverse up to the closest li.folder, select the children img tags and change their source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

object with style property display or visibility: if hidden so no user-action-events possible.
Remove an object == remove from HTML DOM, so no user-action-events possible.

Add an object to HTML DOM so document must be new render. Same if object.style.display was changed.
display changes HTML DOM.

$("#" + what).append('

URL to uploaded document

');  this changes HTML DOM.

NOT same if object.style.visibility was changed: Visibility must have an exist object in HTML DOM.

please use

so,  var imgPointer=document.getElementById("imgID");

put this pointer in an event handler to change imgPointer.src  .

imgPointer (value if ID) is a pointer (value) relative to document an not to .

inside of addLine() change imgPointer.src  .